# Drupal 7 - How to override template for page like node/%/custompage

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have small question about overriding template for Specific page in Drupal like this "node/%/custompage".
As we know for

```
node/% is : page--node.tlp.php 
node/%/edit : page--node--edit.tpl.php

How about a custom page (I created in my custom module) like this 
node/%/custompage
I tried : page--node--custompage.tpl.php
```

But it seem doesn't work.
Thank.

Comment: Please ref : https://www.drupal.org/node/223440

Comment: why not just node--{node-id}.tpl.php? or node--{node-type}.tpl.php? If custompage is a custom content type. If it is to be used in many places you might want to try progzy's suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check "Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions" page: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

Furthermore you can add your own theme hook suggestions. You could implement something like that :

```
   /**
    * Implementation of hook_preprocess_HOOK().
    */
    function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables){
      if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) != 'custompage')
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__custompage';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an mistake, we can use page--node--custompage.tpl.php
I used netbean and have wrong path "page--node--custompage.tpl.php.php", we need to clear all caching before it can be applied.
Thank all